# Regex weird match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm fairly knowledgeable with regex, but I still can't rap my finger around this match.
I have the following string `aaaaaabcaaaaaaa` which is matched by the following regex `caaa|aab|aaa`. What I'm expecting is `caaa, aab, aaa`, and what I'm getting is `aaa, caaa, aaa`.
Can some regex guru please tell me, why I can't get the expected result with this regex?
Thank you.

```js
let string = 'aaaaaabcaaaaaaa',
    regexp = /caaa|aab|aaa/g;
while( match = regexp.exec( string ) )
  console.log( match );
```

Comment: Regex matches a string from left to right. You get expected non-overlapping matches.

Comment: It's very simple - the beginning of the string matchs the final alteration in the regex. The string is examined in order, the first alteration will not be matched first, if it's all the way at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Than how can I change the regex to match in the expected order, without changing the string?

Comment: Just match for each alternative separately.

Comment: But if I have a larger dataset to match, and a larger regex (think dictionary) won't it be inefficient?

Comment: "*But if I have a larger dataset to match, and a larger regex (think dictionary) won't it be inefficient?*" **Yes**, it will be. Which is a reason regexes match the way they do - in sequence, rather than walking back and forth through the string matching different bits from it.